TypeError: createContext is not a function in Next.js App
I'm working on a Next.js application and encountering a recurring TypeError: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createContext) is not a function error whenever I try running my app using npm run dev. This error occurs when trying to compile various components, all of which appear related to Radix UI components being utilized within a <ThemeProvider>.
Error Details:
TypeError: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED [MODULE_0__].createContext) is not a function
at eval (webpack-internal://...:11:114) ...

TypeError: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createContext) is not a function
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@radix-ui/react-direction/dist/index.mjs:11:114)
    at (rsc)/./node_modules/@radix-ui/react-direction/dist/index.mjs (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\vendor-chunks\@radix-ui.js:300:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@radix-ui/react-navigation-menu/dist/index.mjs:31:83)
    at (rsc)/./node_modules/@radix-ui/react-navigation-menu/dist/index.mjs (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\vendor-chunks\@radix-ui.js:330:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/components/ui/navigation-menu.tsx:17:89)
    at (rsc)/./src/components/ui/navigation-menu.tsx (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\app\page.js:392:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/components/Navigation.tsx:10:88)
    at (rsc)/./src/components/Navigation.tsx (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\app\page.js:354:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/layout.tsx:11:80)
    at (rsc)/./src/app/layout.tsx (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\app\page.js:294:1)
    at Function.__webpack_require__ (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at async e9 (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:396515)  
    at async tb (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:400212)  
    at async tS (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:400773)  
    at async tR (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:36:2130)    
    at async E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:36:2722 {       
  digest: '1970504122'
}
 ⨯ TypeError: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createContext) is not a function
    at __webpack_require__ (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at __webpack_require__ (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (./src/components/ui/navigation-menu.tsx:17:89)
    at (rsc)/./src/components/ui/navigation-menu.tsx (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\app\page.js:392:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (./src/components/Navigation.tsx:10:88)
    at (rsc)/./src/components/Navigation.tsx (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\app\page.js:354:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (./src/app/layout.tsx:11:80)
    at (rsc)/./src/app/layout.tsx (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\app\page.js:294:1)
    at Function.__webpack_require__ (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
digest: "4067933667"
 ⨯ TypeError: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createContext) is not a function
    at __webpack_require__ (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at __webpack_require__ (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (./src/components/ui/navigation-menu.tsx:17:89)
    at (rsc)/./src/components/ui/navigation-menu.tsx (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\app\page.js:392:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (./src/components/Navigation.tsx:10:88)
    at (rsc)/./src/components/Navigation.tsx (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\app\page.js:354:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (./src/app/layout.tsx:11:80)
    at (rsc)/./src/app/layout.tsx (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\app\page.js:294:1)
    at Function.__webpack_require__ (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
digest: "4067933667"
 ⨯ TypeError: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createContext) is not a function
    at __webpack_require__ (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at __webpack_require__ (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (./src/components/ui/navigation-menu.tsx:17:89)
    at (rsc)/./src/components/ui/navigation-menu.tsx (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\app\page.js:392:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (./src/components/Navigation.tsx:10:88)
    at (rsc)/./src/components/Navigation.tsx (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\app\page.js:354:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (./src/app/layout.tsx:11:80)
    at (rsc)/./src/app/layout.tsx (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\app\page.js:294:1)
    at Function.__webpack_require__ (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
digest: "1970504122"
 ⨯ TypeError: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createContext) is not a function
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@radix-ui/react-direction/dist/index.mjs:11:114)
    at (rsc)/./node_modules/@radix-ui/react-direction/dist/index.mjs (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\vendor-chunks\@radix-ui.js:300:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@radix-ui/react-navigation-menu/dist/index.mjs:31:83)
    at (rsc)/./node_modules/@radix-ui/react-navigation-menu/dist/index.mjs (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\vendor-chunks\@radix-ui.js:330:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/components/ui/navigation-menu.tsx:17:89)
    at (rsc)/./src/components/ui/navigation-menu.tsx (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\app\page.js:392:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/components/Navigation.tsx:10:88)
    at (rsc)/./src/components/Navigation.tsx (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\app\page.js:354:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/layout.tsx:11:80)
    at (rsc)/./src/app/layout.tsx (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\app\page.js:294:1)
    at Function.__webpack_require__ (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at async e9 (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:396515)  
    at async tb (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:400212)  
    at async tS (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:400773)  
    at async tR (E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:36:2130)    
    at async E:\Ai\hijraah-website\hijraah\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:36:2722 {       
  digest: '1970504122',
  page: '/'
}
 ○ Compiling /_error ...
 ✓ Compiled /_error in 13.4s (1295 modules)
 GET / 500 in 23476ms

Code Details:
The error seems to stem from the integration of Radix UI libraries and possibly how React contexts are implemented within the app. Below is a snippet where one such context is used in the hijraah/src/app/layout.tsx file within a ClerkProvider:
// layout.tsx snippet
import { ClerkProvider } from '@clerk/nextjs';

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <ClerkProvider>
      <html lang="en">
        <body>
          <Navigation />
          <main>{children}</main>
          <Footer />
        </body>
      </html>
    </ClerkProvider>
  );
}

Attempted Solutions:

Checked and ensured correct imports for createContext from React.
Checked for any potential issues with mismatched React versions across packages.
Restarted the development server after clearing the .next cache.

Expected Outcome:
I expected the application to run without such type errors, especially since createContext should be a defined function imported from React.
**Actual Outcome:}>
The application fails to compile, throwing the mentioned TypeError related to createContext.
Setup:

Next.js version: 14.2.3
React version across different parts of the app: 18.2.0
Usage of Radix UI components and @clerk/nextjs.

Question:
What could be causing this createContext error and how can I resolve it to ensure smooth integration of these UI components within my Next.js application?

Try putting ClerkProvider as a child of body?

is React imported on your file : hijraah/src/app/layout.tsx ? because it needs to be. it seems like createContext is not defined which makes me think you didn't import React

My guess is its an problem with the integration from the themeprovider in a server component. Lots of the packages are not ready for app router. They are missing the "use client" to work. A possible work around is wrap the the provider in a component thats has the "use client" description. In your case:
"use client"
import { ClerkProvider } from '@clerk/nextjs';

export const MyThemeWrapper = ({children}) => {
   return(
       <ClerkProvider>
           {children}
       </ClerkProvider>
   )
}

and in layout.tsx
export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <MyThemeProvider>
      <html lang="en">
        <body>
          <Navigation />
          <main>{children}</main>
          <Footer />
        </body>
      </html>
    <MyThemeProvider>
  );
}


Add:
"use client"
import 'swiper/css'
...

That will fix the issue
https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/7568
